# z Axis: Is possible to show "min" and "max" or grid?

Tags: highcharts

my chart is this:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/grid-light

why "min" and "max" of z Axis aren't show in chart ?
Is there a way to show min and max?

And is possible to show a grid also for z Axis ?

like this image:

http://i61.tinypic.com/28a5avn.png

Thank you

Comment: How would you like to show min and max? Lines? Highlighted points? Text somewhere?

Comment: Have you see the image in the link? I would like to have lines, and value min and max... But how i don't know... Do you think that is possible?

Comment: For example, is possible to have lines (plotlines) on z-axis?

Comment: I was misunderstanding a bit. I see what you mean now. I'm not sure at the moment.

Comment: Are not sure about what? Do you understanding what i mean? My chart is small portion of earth. So must be longitudine and latitude. I want that on "bottom" there will be also the lines of z-axis. There will be a grid... Because the lines of x-axis are the lines of longitudine.... And the other lines should be the lines of latitude. if you see the image in the link of first post, you understanding....   Do you think there is a way to achieve it?

Comment: I think, he meant that is not sure about solution at this moment. Relax :) Anyway, actually zAxis doesn't have such option. Open [source code](http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.src.js) and search for `zAxis` - you will find out that only min and max options are used. There are plans to add fully working zAxis (just like xAxis and yAxis),  but we don't have any ETA for this.